# What is quickest, least number of taps possible on Apple Watch to “check-in” with somebody?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, apple-watch

I am looking for a way to contact my spouse when I am at work and too busy to text. I want to use my Apple Watch in the quickest way possible, ideally just 1 or two taps, to send an automated text or whatever, just so that my spouse gets some sort of signal that I am busy but "checking-in". I have dangerous job that sometimes goes 12+ hours later than expected, so being able to very briefly "check-in" with a few watch taps would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you use Siri for this?

Comment: Sorry, cannot us Siri!

Comment: I feel like there's a simpler way with the Workflow app, but I'm got mine stuck and don't have time to fix it right now. But workflow supports a watch complication, which I think can run a workflow with a single tap, and you can make a workflow that's just "send this person this text", which *seems* like it'd be a one-tap message which is what you want. Assuming it all works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the [Workflow](https://appsto.re/us/2IzJ2.i) (iTunes link) app can indeed do this!

Workflow supports showing a workflow as a complication, with one tap to trigger that workflow.

A workflow can be as simple as "using this text, send a message to this person".

Putting those two together, you can have a two-tap system to send an iMessage or SMS to someone: activate the complication, and push "send".

Here's the workflow I used to test this:

- **Text**: This block holds the text you want to send, and passes it to the next block
- **Send Message**: Takes text and sends it to a predetermined recipient

[image: Screenshot illustrating the above sample blocks]

The Workflow widget is the GPS marker icon on the top-left.

[image: screenshot of my Apple Watch]

[image: the text dictation screen]

*Nota bene:* If you have multiple workflows visible on your watch, the complication cycles through them throughout the day. If you only have one, it only shows the one.

Comment: Thanks so much for this awesome explanation. This is exactly what I want. Your answer will push me over the edge to buy an Apple Watch!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the Do Button by ifttt

https://ifttt.com/products/do/button

You can create a button/recipe that sends an e-mail or sms to your significant other saying 'I'm Alive' or something.

Then all you ever have to do it just tap the button and the program will do the rest :) So at most it should be 2 taps,

1. Open App
2. Click button to start recipe

I do not have an Apple Watch but it might be possible to do it in 1 if it allows you to add a shortcut in glances or something.

Comment: Looking at Do Button, it has a glance but not a complication. Still might be faster than my Workflow option.

Comment: If you have your iPhone with you, it might be easier too. You can add it to your notification center. Then it is as quick as pulling down notification center and clicking the button

Answer (score 2):

One press, 4 taps:

1. Push side button
2. Use wheel or tap spouse
3. Tap center
4. Tap message icon
5. Tap canned message
6. Message sent!

Hope this helps...

Comment: Please check your formatting, right now the answer is very hard to understand. To fix it, you can use the "edit" link below the text.

Comment: I understand your response, thanks for the info! I am hoping there is an app that can accomplish something similar in less steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without any clicks with Siri. Make sure you have "Hey Siri" enabled and then you can do something like:

> - Hey Siri! Tell my wife/husband I'm alive
> - Hey Siri! Send

You also have to have your spouse set in the contacts.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I will have to do this discretely and will not be able to talk to my wrist